# How to display an image inside a circle inside an arc in d3

Tags: d3.js, path, geometry

I've got a sunburst chart drawn and this works fine. I've tried to add a circle that displays an image within each segment (path) and I can't get them to show up. Weirdly if I inspect the DOM the circles are exactly where I want them to be in the tree but they simply don't display. Is anybody able to help?

````
          .create("svg")
          .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, width])
          .style("font-size", ".6rem");

        const g = svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${width / 2})`);

        const path = g
          .append("g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
          .join("path")
          .attr("fill", (d) => {
            while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent;
            return color(d.data.name);
          })
          .attr("fill-opacity", (d) =>
            arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.7 : 0.5) : 0
          )
          .attr("d", (d) => arc(d.current));

        path
          .filter((d) => d.children)
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .on("click", clicked);

        const defs = path.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs");

        const iconPattern = defs
          .append("pattern")
          .attr("id", "iconPattern")
          .attr("height", 1)
          .attr("width", 1)
          .attr("x", "0")
          .attr("y", "0");

        iconPattern
          .append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
            return d.data.img;
          })
          .attr("height", 15)
          .attr("width", 15);

        path
          .append("circle")
          .attr("r", 5)
          .attr("cy", 0)
          .attr("cx", 0)
          .attr("fill", "url(#iconPattern)");

        path
          .append("title")
          .attr("pointer-events", "none")
          .attr("color", "white")
          .on("click", clicked)
          .text((d) => d.data.name);```
````

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: Sure see here https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-circle-test-xoqv9. I also can't get an emoji do display in the centre using d3moji. Bit weird how I can show the circle...

Comment: I don't think you can append elements under a <circle> tag, the <emoji> element should be a sibling of  the  <circle>

Comment: even so, the circle elements should still render and they don't?

Comment: instead of appending <path> after enter(), append <g>, and under <g> append <path>, <circle>, <text>

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, can you provide a snippet please?

Comment: I've done some changes in your code (see the answer). Let me know if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code sample refactored to add **g** instead of **path** and add **path**, **circle**, and **text** under **g**:

```
const segments = g
  .selectAll("g.segment")
  .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
  .join("g")
  .classed("segment", true)

segments.append("path)
  .attr("fill", ...)
   .attr("fill-opacity", ...);

segments.filter((d) => d.children)
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", clicked);

const defs = segments.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs");

const iconPattern = defs
  .append("pattern")
  ...
iconPattern
  .append("image")
  ...
        
segments.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("fill", "url(#iconPattern)");

segments.append("title")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr("color", "white")
  .on("click", clicked)
  .text((d) => d.data.name);
```